# Blender 2.79 crashes when in material view

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, error

I am running blender on windows 8 64 bit and have AMD Radeon HD 7670M and Intel HD Graphics 4000.

Whenever I try to enter material view on a layer with even a cube, it will instantly close. Other things that cause the file to crash include; texture mode and system tab in user preference.

I have tried using other versions such as 2.79b to no avail. I refuse to use 2.8 or later for this current project, I prefer blender render and am still transitioning to eevee.

All of this started when I updated AMD Radeon.

Here is the file I'm having trouble with, it's for a fan project:
[image]

Comment: Runs fine for me. I'd suggest downgrading the radeon again

Comment: @WhatAMesh You're probably right, but I can't remember the previous version I used.

Comment: @WhatAMesh what version would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downgraded the driver to AMD Radeon HD 7600M and it now works perfectly. I will keep the drivers with that range to prevent further issues.

Comment: Glad to see it worked